Some queries in Grafana Alerting not working - 429 code errors
I am trying to set an alert on Grafana. My data source is Google Managed Prometheus. The query that I am using to set an alert on is:
max by(cluster_name, namespace_name, pod_name, container_name) (max_over_time(kubernetes_io:container_memory_limit_utilization{memory_type="non-evictable"}[1h]))

I think that it is important to mention that we are having a quite big number of Kubernetes clusters, pods and containers. When I am trying to run this query I am getting an error:
Failed to evaluate queries and expressions: failed to execute conditions: failed to execute query A: client_error: client error: 429
Considering that 429 error message I suppose that I am hitting some rate limit - either set by Grafana itself, either from Google Cloud Monitoring, either from Google Managed Prometheus (maybe someone can help me a bit with the direction of what I need to adjust). On the other hand, by checking the console I can see that the error thrown is a 400 - failed to load resource.
The Grafana version that we use is Grafana 9.0.5
I expect the query to work. I mean it is quite heavy, but not huge. Or I do not know how to define what a heavy query is, or how to evaluate that and what the limits imposed by Grafana are.

Try running the query using e.g. Metrics Explorer directly against Cloud Monitoring; reduce the query complexity (1|few clusters). Check the Google-managed Prometheus logs. Check the Cloud Console's quotas. Contact Cloud Support.

Do you need the max by clause?

The GCP general quotas are not surpassed (also maybe there are some instantenous quotas?); my prometheus is scrapping metrics from multiple GCP projects and multiple GKE clusters; this is my use case. I using this query to setup a general alert; Do you have any suggestion on how can I simplify the queries; or maybe split the workload? Also I do not understand from where the 429 error is coming.

If you pay for Cloud Support, this would be a good use case because, I assume, the Cloud Support engineers will be able to trace the query in its entirety and understand where the issue arises. If not, my earlier suggestions stand: (1) check logs; (2) reduce the query "cost" (by halving) until you're able to isolate the point|place at which the error occurs. Do you use recording rules (see Managed rule evaluation). In my experience, Google's engineering team is responsive to this type of issue too
